# Mean of fractions or fraction of means? When to use mediant and when to use mean?

Tags: average

When would we use the mediant?

Clarifying the problem:
I was working on some numbers. De data had duration of a job, the number of steps to complete a job and the starting date of a job. All rows had similar data. I wanted to know the average duration per step. Somehow I got in the process of overthinking.

What I was doing, is what I would normally do when computing an average, so in my case:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{d_i}{s_i}
$$
In which $d$ is the duration of a job, $s$ the number of steps to complete a job and $i$ the job (I am neglecting the optional time binning here).
But why would I not just compute the average duration and the average number of steps, divide those and use that number, so:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n d_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n s_i} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n d_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n s_i}
$$
also called the mediant.

I understand math in the way that I know these are not computing to the same value in general. So the question is more fundamental I guess? Why can't we use the last one, just simply because an average divided by an average is not an average?
When would we use the last expression (mediant)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to compute.  The average and the mediant are two different numbers, but I can't tell from what you have said which one of them would be appropriate here.  It's not even clear what you mean by a "step".  Can a step be repeated on a particular job?  Do the numbers reflect this?

Comment: I know these numbers are different, the question would be: when would someone use the mediant?
the goal is to compute the average duration per step (which would be the first expression).
I just have data on the number of steps, no if steps are repeated. It is just an example, we could also use distance for d and time for s for the values and a job would be a some path, but like all jobs not all paths are equal

Comment: Yes, you already said you want to compute the average duration per said.  This phrase has more than one possible meaning.  It might mean the average duration of one of the steps defined in the operations manual.  It might mean the every length of time an employee spends performing one of those steps.  These are two different things and will have two different values, requiring two different calculations.